# NpgSql Entity Framework SQL Command with parameter

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

I'm trying to pass a parameter with a SQL statement using Entity Framework and NpgSql. Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"UPDATE dbo.""AuditorQaNotes"" SET ""IsRead""='true' WHERE ""ClientOrderMappingId""= (@mappingId)", new NpgsqlParameter("mappingId", DbType.Int16).Value = mappingId);
```

I get an error

> ERROR: 42703: column \"mappingid\" does not exist

How do I reference the parameter name in the SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read the [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) on passing parameters with raw queries.